# Simplified Configuration wsHttpBinding

Tags: wcf, binding

I'm having a simple WCF service, deployed to IIS. I used [simplified configuration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee530014.aspx) with `BasicHttpBinding`, which worked fine.

Now I wanted to add Username/Password authentication and used wsHttpBinding. In the document above it is stated:

> In .NET Framework 4, the  element is optional. When a service
>   does not define any endpoints, an endpoint for each base address and
>   contract implemented are added to the service. The base address is
>   appended to the contract name to determine the endpoint and the
>   **binding is determined by the address scheme**.

What does this mean, how am I supposed to configure the `wsHttpBinding` binding by address scheme?

My config looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding>
          <security mode="Message">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>      
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior> 
          <serviceCredentials>
            <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom" customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="SampleWebservice.CustomValidator,SampleWebservice" />
          </serviceCredentials>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
 <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>  
</configuration>
```

This is Windows Server 2008, IIS 7.

It seems, the service is not picking up the wsBinding settings, as I can always see a `BasicHttpBinding` in the downloaded svc-file. Am I missing something?

---

**EDIT**

I applied the changes suggested by user stevedocious to alter my web.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="SampleWebservice.SampleWebservice.Sample" behaviorConfiguration="customServiceBehaviour">
        <endpoint contract="IMetadataExchange" binding="mexHttpBinding" address="mex" />
        <endpoint contract="SampleWebservice.SampleWebservice.ISample" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="bindingConfiguration" address="" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="bindingConfiguration">
          <security mode="Message">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>      
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="customServiceBehaviour"> 
          <serviceCredentials>
            <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom" customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="SampleWebservice.CustomValidator,SampleWebservice" />
          </serviceCredentials>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
 <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>  
</configuration>
```

However, the metadata can't be exposed. Checking the service with the browser states, that my metadata publishing is currently disabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to create an endpoint if you want to use anything other than the basicHttpBinding with the http/https address scheme.

In your binding definition add a name attribute

> < binding name="myWSBinding" ... >

then add a bindingConfiguration and binding parameter to your endpoint definition

> < endpoint binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingCongifuration="myWSBinding" ... >

Comment: I followed your approach, but it leaves me with "Metadata publishing for this service is currently disabled." when I check my svc-File in the browser. See above for applied changes.

Comment: Your service name has the same name as your endpoint contract. The name of the service should be the concrete implementation of your class. If you've defined the ServiceContract on an interface then the endpoint contract name should be the name of the interface.

Comment: Thanks, that resolved the issue, I had to specify the ServiceContract in the endpoint, which is the interface `ISample`.